# Long running console command slows down

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel

### Initial text

I created console in Laravel project. The command takes html data from one table, checks two pattern matches for each record by preg_match. If it returns true, updates are being done to other table's record that has the same attribute as record from the first table that is currently in focus in foreach loop.
Number of records is cca 3500

After cca 150 iterations, command dramatically slows down, and I need one day for getting the command done.

I read all similar issues from this forum but they didn't help me. Not even the answer about forcing garbage collection.

Code is like following:

```
$ras = RecordsA::all();
$pattern = '/===this is the pattern===/';
foreach($ras as $ra){
    $html = $ra->html;
    $rb = RecordB::where("url", $ra->url)->first();
    $rb->phone = preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : $rb->phone;
    $rb->save();
}
```

I was searching for possible issue about *preg_match* performance but it was unsuccessful.

Did anybody meet such problem?

---

### For MMMTroy update

I forgot to say I also tried custom but similar to your code:

```
$counter = DB::select("select count(*) as count from records_a")->first();
//Pattern for Wiktor Stribiżew :)
    $pattern = '/Telefon:([^<])+</';
for($i = 0; $i < $counter->count; $i+=150){
    $ras = RecordsA::limit(150)->offset($i);
    foreach($ras as $ra){
        $html = $ra->html;
        $rb = RecordB::where("url", $ra->url)->first();
        $rb->phone = preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : $rb->phone;
        $rb->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the pattern? Heard of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)?

Comment: I updated text. There I wrote pattern.

Comment: The pattern is very well written, there should be no issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pagination via OFFSET" is Order(N*N).  You would be better off with Order(N), so "remember where you left off".

[*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Comment: This seems that is solution. After ordering by whatever, loop started working awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you a running out of memory.  Laravel has a handy method to "chunk" results which dramatically reduces the amount of memory by limiting the amount of items you are looping.  Try something like this.

```
$pattern = '/===this is the pattern===/';    
Records::chunk(100, function($ras)use($pattern){
    foreach($ras as $ra){
        $html = $ra->html;
        $rb = RecordB::where("url", $ra->url)->first();
        $rb->phone = preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : $rb->phone;
        $rb->save();
    }
});
```

What this is doing is grabbing 100 records at a time, and then looping through those.  Once done, it creates an offset and grabs the next records in the database.  This will prevent the entire loop from being stored in memory.

Comment: Please check recently my updated text. Does my way of chunking differ in functionality case?

Comment: In theory it should be the same thing, but I may see an error in the new code you just added.  Shouldn't $ras = RecordsA::limit(150)->offset($i); include the ->get() at the end?

Comment: yes. i forgot to put it here. but it is in source code.

Comment: I'd give the chunk method a shot.  While in theory it should be the same as the offset, I've been surprised before.  If not, at least it's much prettier.  Have you tried lowering the limit to something like 50?  You really shouldn't be running into memory issues after only 150 iterations, so if 50 doesn't work you might need to start going down the road that Wiktor mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Does your database grow while looping through? What happens if `RecordB` is not found and it returns `null`? Feels to me your table for `RecordB` is growing, causing the search query to slow down.

Had recently similar problems and hitting memory limits. There is 1 thing whats the number 1 of slowing down stuff and leaking memory.
The `DB::$queryLog` (disable it with: `DB::disableQueryLog();`). Everytime there is a query called, the query string will be stored in a variable.

Perhaps one of those things is causing it, but else the code looks fine to me.

Comment: Negative. My db is not growing. I just update 2nd table according to html data from 1st table. I had tried to loop this without updating and left preg_match check and the same problem persisted. While looping without preg_match checking and updating finishes in few fragments of a second.